# Can I give "my colleagues weren't motivated" as a reason for leaving a company?

Tags: interviewing

It's not the only reason I left, but it was one of them. Basically almost all my colleagues weren't very motivated. They will follow instructions, but never come up with ideas of their own. There could for example be a [big event] in the industry, but I'd have nobody to discuss it with.

I am wondering if this is a good reason to cite in an interview or if it will be viewed as disparaging a former employer, with all its associated problems.

Comment: Easy to outperform them and advance

Comment: @BigMadAndy it's not my company but I still want it to succeed - I want it to grow, expand, become world-leading, and I want to be able to say I was part of it. I do not understand why you think that is immature.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere> that is, assuming the company was big enough that promotions were a thing.

Comment: I don't see the relation between this question and the linked one - I clearly have to say something, question is whether I can say this.

Comment: @Allure What's wrong with saying, "I left due to cultural differences?" This is literally true, in this case.

Comment: @employee-X I would have to elaborate on that answer though, and then what do I say?

Comment: This might be a better duplicate target: [Should I list “boredom” as a reason for leaving my previous job in an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/80177/26699) As Joe's answer points out, the obvious follow up question is "Why should we expect that you won't find your colleagues here similarly lacking and leave?"

Comment: @ColleenV there is a difference though - I obviously cannot tell from the outside, but the interviewer might know. Comparatively with boredom, I'm the one who knows what I find boring/not boring, while the interviewer would not know.

Comment: @Allure You are the one that is judging your coworkers to be insufficiently motivated. Why do you think the interviewer would know what your opinion will be of the people you might end up working with? What if only half of them are deficient in your opinion? I don’t think it’s that different.

Comment: @ColleenV because I provide(d) examples of why I considered my colleagues unmotivated, and the interviewer is presumably able to tell if their company's employees would have behaved differently in those situations.

Comment: @Allure if you’re interviewing with me and you tell me you left your job because your coworkers sucked, I’m going to assume the problem was you and not your coworkers. If you ask me about the company culture around innovation  and whether it would be a good fit for you, that would be more positive. The advice in the duplicates is that it’s a bad idea to give certain sorts of reasons for leaving your previous company in an interview, and your reason falls into that category.

Comment: @ColleenV if I'm interviewing with you and I tell you that I left because my coworkers were unmotivated, e.g. there was a big conference in our company's field of expertise which generated a lot of talking points with potential actionable things we could do, but nobody was interested in talking & nobody wanted to try anything either without explicit instructions from management, would you still assume that I was the problem? If the answer to this is in the duplicates please point it out, because I have not seen it.

Comment: @ColleenV In the same way, if we assume that the new company is also in the same field of expertise, the interviewer *should* know if their company's employees did talk about the big conference and if they implemented anything in response. If the answer to both of these is "yes" - or "no", for that matter - then they also know the answer to "Why should we expect that you won't find your colleagues here similarly lacking and leave?" I, on the other hand, cannot tell from the outside.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

> my colleagues weren't very motivated. They will follow instructions, but never come up with ideas of their own

Sounds pretty disparaging to me.

Instead of focusing on what you didn't like about your former co-workers, try flipping it around and discuss what you want from future co-workers - something like *"I'm looking for opportunities to work with highly motivated industry leaders"* perhaps.

That changes the likely impression you'll leave from being someone who doesn't think much of your colleagues, to someone who wants to respect them a lot, while still meaning essentially the same thing.

Comment: I'm trying, but I just can't seem to see how your alternative is any better in meaning than the original phrasing. Except that the original phrasing is specific and something that is actionable.

Comment: @rubenvb as I understand, the point is to express this positively, like "I prefer X", instead of blaming previous workplace for "not X".

Comment: One is blaming (they didnt meet my standard and wont go up to me), the other one is improving youself (I didnt like the standard they have, so I'm looking for a better match)

Comment: Sure, I get that you're trying to sugar-coat it. But by doing that in the way you suggest, you're also removing anything specific from the statement, and leaving the other party with no way to improve the situation (should they want to). I know exit interviews aren't the ideal place to give "nasty" feedback, but well, it's somewhat silly not fully expressing the facts as you see them.

Comment: @rubenvb I don't believe this question is about the exit interview.

Comment: @rubenvb I see your point, but your posture would be more adequate if he was still working there... not in this situation.

Comment: Ah indeed, it seems I misread the question.

Comment: I like the spirit of the answer, but the phrasing (“looking for opportunities to work with highly motivated industry leaders”) sounds like from a tacky job ad copy — soulless, faux hip marketing language.

Comment: i think it's worth mentioning: the most effective way to do this is to give _some other  answer_ when they ask "why did you leave?" and find a _different_ opportunity to express an interest in working with motivated colleagues. if you give the suggested quote as a direct answer to "why did you leave?" then it is sugarcoating but ultimately still a little disparaging. if you say the suggested quote with a different segue, earlier or later in the interview, you get to say what you wanted to say without throwing any shade.

Comment: @KonradRudolph. That is the perfect type of answer to give at an exit interview.

Comment: @MadPhysicist As stated further above, the question is (probably) not about an exit interview.

Answer (score 26):

> I am wondering if this is a good reason to cite in an interview or if it will be viewed as disparaging a former employer, with all its associated problems.

I wouldn't mention it. It makes it sound as if you have a minimum threshold for how motivated employees need to be for you to stay on board. Do their employees meet that minimum threshold? Who knows but even if they did you still come across as being a bit judgmental.

Really, *all* I'd say if I were asked why I'm considering leaving a current employer is: I've learned as much as I can at my current job and am eager for new challenges and new opportunities to learn.

That said, it's fine to mention that as the reason in an exit interview but not in a job interview you're serious about.

Comment: Why would it not be good to talk about this early? If this is a reason to leave the previous job, I don't see why OP would want to keep it undiscussed just to get the new job and realize that it's not better there

Comment: @lucidbrot You *should* ensure that all of your concerns are addressed in an interview. However, you *also* must demonstrate that you're capable of working with other personality types, who have different concerns. You have to find a way to phrase it which isn't off-putting. When you meet the team, ask them what their favorite things about the culture are, perhaps? If they answer seriously, it will give you a clue as to what motivates them. There are probably even more insightful questions you could ask.

Answer (score 16):

I'm somewhat against the conventional wisdom. Everyone knows you have issues with your previous employer, or you wouldn't have left. I don't think there's much point in trying to pretend you didn't. The reason people ask in an interview is because you don't want to land back in the same situation that caused you to leave. It's okay to lose an opportunity if it's not the right opportunity.

That being said, you should do it with tact, and make sure you are not so vague that people could interpret your comments to match companies it shouldn't match. I would word it something like, "My colleagues didn't share my interest in professional development and innovation. What kind of opportunities do you have to encourage that at your company?"

Comment: You might well have left just because the grass wasn't green enough on your side.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Which is just a metaphor you had issues.

Answer (score 11):

You never give detailed reasons as to why exactly you left.

If you have been with the company not too long, say up to two years, something general followed by "was not what I expected" is usually fine. If you were with it longer, something along the lines of looking for new opportunities is the way to hint at not having a career path forward in your old company. Or mentioning that something "was changing" tells that you used to be happy in that job, but now aren't anymore. Stick with the general, and weave something positive in there. In your case you could say that you started working in a fantastic team, but then people left and the team spirit changed and does not fit your expectations anymore. Be ready for a follow-up question about what you expect from the team you work with - but if it comes, you already turned the conversation to what you want from your new job, away from the old one.

Never forget that any halfway smart employer understands that one day, he will be your previous workplace, and the way you speak about your last job is the way you will be speaking about him in the future.

Comment: Exactly. More likely to cause harm than good. It is unlikely that your reason will ever be passed to the right people. You may find that your new company is worse and you want to come back. You may be flagged as a person with a bad attitude rather than someone with a legitimate reason.

Answer (score 6):

Of course it's a valid reason. In fact, it's an excellent reason. I know exactly how this feels: you are interested, enthusiastic, willing to learn, full of life energy. You care for things, and you want to solve problems even though they might not be in your job description. On the other hand, your environment is full of people who don't care. They are not there to solve problems, but to sell their time, to keep the chairs warm, to participate in meetings that will justify their salaries. They need to be told what to do, and they will only do what they are told. Their motto is "the more complicated, the better".

Any future employer who understands this will wellcome you with open hands. He will know that people like you are rare and valuable like a treasure. They will know that people like you are an asset to a company, the future Elon Musks and Jeff Bezos, whereas the other people are a liability, like furniture and machines. Almost every job advertisement out there says that they are looking for "highly motivated people". That's you.

And this is what is so wrong with our society. Everybody lies, everybody pretends. People work in jobs they hate and we have learned and accepted that this is somehow how it is supposed to be. It is not. I'm surprised and disappointed at how many people are advising you to shut up, to be like others, fit in the box. I'm willing to bet that many of them hate their jobs.

One thing is true though - citing others as the reason for you leaving slightly misses the point. So instead of "I left because my colleagues were unmotivated" it could be better to say "I left because I couldn't realize my full potential".

Comment: You make a good and honest point here - I would just add that it's about how you say things, not what you say that matters here. "I want to bring ideas and innovation, and be challenged by those around me so we arrive at the best possible outcome" is going to be way better than "I'm the only one who comes up with ideas, everyone else is just a dullard who does what they're told". The key here is to turn every negative thing into a positive - but I agree that there's no need to "keep quiet" on any topic. There's also no need to raise things that aren't helpful though ;-)